# how I could encode fast video rgb planar format?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, cimg

I compile a command and use this command for encode and then speed up the video

```
g++ -Wall -o main lena2.cpp  -lpng -lz -lX11 -lpthread -fopenmp -std=c++11  ;./main | ffmpeg -y -f rawvideo -pixel_format gbrp -video_size 1024x768 -i - -c:v h264 -pix_fmt yuv420p video.mov

ffmpeg -y  -i video.mov -filter:v "setpts=PTS/8"  fastvideo.mov;
```

this is the code that i compile

```
#include <iostream>
#include "CImg.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace cimg_library;

int main()
{
   const unsigned int width=1024;
   const unsigned int height=768;

   // Basic frame we will draw in
   CImg<unsigned char> image(width,height,1,3);

   unsigned char magenta[] = {255,0,255};

   // We are going to output 300 frames of 1024x768 RGB raw video
   // ... making a 10s long video at 30fps
   int radius=100;
   int cx=100;
   int cy=100;
   for(int frame=0;frame<300;frame++){
      // Start with black - it shows fewer stains ;-)
      image.fill(0);
      image.draw_circle(cx,cy,radius,magenta);

      // Move and re-colour circle
      cx+=2; cy++; if(magenta[1]!=255){magenta[1]++;}

      // Output to ffmpeg to make video, in planar GBR format
      // i.e. run program like this
      // ./main | ffmpeg -y -f rawvideo -pixel_format gbrp -video_size 1024x768 -i - -c:v h264 -pix_fmt yuv420p video.mov
      char* s=reinterpret_cast<char*>(image.data()+(width*height));   // Get start of G plane
      std::cout.write(s,width*height);                                // Output it
      s=reinterpret_cast<char*>(image.data()+2*(width*height));       // Get start of B plane
      std::cout.write(s,width*height);                                // Output it
      s=reinterpret_cast<char*>(image.data());                        // Get start of R plane
      std::cout.write(s,width*height);                                // Output it
   }
}
```

but the rgb to video conversion take more of 20 minutes for 45000 frames

How I could generate video.mov faster

please help me

Comment: Compile with optimizations turned on?

Comment: To ask about improvements of already working code rather ask at [SE Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) please.

Comment: I dont know what optimizations I should use for aceleratte

Comment: ok I will ask IN se code review

Comment: try `g++ -march=native -O3 ...`

Comment: I use this " -march=native -O3" but only speed up 10% of fast

Comment: Try timing how long it takes to generate the frames in CImg but discard them to `/dev/null` and see if the time is taken by creating them or encoding them - i.e. if it is CImg or `ffmpeg` that takes the time. `time ./main > /dev/null` without `ffmpeg`.

Comment: hi i use this and takes 15 min , I dont need all frames to video only 1/8 then i use if(frame % 8 ==0){
      std::cout.write(s2,width*height);  
} for reduce this works well but only speed up x3 times if exist any way for speed more please tell me